# How to disable "target" and its sub-folders in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How to hide the below folders from the package explorer view? Image below

1. "target" and all its sub folders
2. other empty directories like "src"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java, you need to [access to the element filter](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg21635.html).
It can be present for other plugins as well, like this [DB explorer](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/zigen/home/plugin/dbviewer/news_en.html):

[image]

This illustrates how to specify a name/regex for all the directories you don't want to see (exclude) in the package explorer.