# How do I refresh or clean or generally deal with Eclipse target folders?

Tags: java, eclipse, structure

My webapp, within Eclipse, shows an error on the base folder which trickles down to the target folder, highlighting a change I have already made in my main source days ago. Cleaning the project does not get rid of this. How do I clean or refresh this target folder from showcasing old errors that I have already corrected? What's the proper protocol on dealing with this folder?

I am unsure if this is an Eclipse only issue.

EDIT: I am aware of [How to disable "target" and its sub-folders in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590986/how-to-disable-target-and-its-sub-folders-in-eclipse) but I am not sure if this is what I want to do yet. I'd like to solve this problem without disabling the folder if possible, or really I'd like to do whatever is standard.

Comment: Are you saying the cause of errors is old code?. May I ask when do you receive this error in the beginning, or middle of a project?

Comment: I love Eclipse, but this is exactly what drives me mad about maven integration with Eclipse. Switched finally to InteliJ Idea and much happier so far.

Comment: @Akyllite, yes the cause of the errors is old code, as in code that no longer exists. A class was renamed and the code calling a method within that class has been properly adjusted, but the `target` folder still contains the older version. I'm just wondering how to deal with this.

Comment: @Kris, unfortunately changing IDE's is not an option for me.

Comment: @Akyllite, I should also mention that this does not affect my project from running properly. It's just not right for it to tell me there are errors when they do not exist.

Comment: So the errors are problems found in the project tab. Correct me if I am wrong is it possible that it is not related to your project at all the errors. If that is the case wouldn't, Right-Click current project > close other projects, then errors wouldn't show on the  problems tab. The problem tab gives out a worldy issue found in all projects that are open. However if it is closed it wont show it.

Comment: First, I figured out if I cleaned the project it cleaned the target folder. Not sure why it didn't do this before. And secondly, I am 100% sure it was old code. `Sample.sample();` became `SampleController.sample();` in my sample MVC app, and it's my code. It didn't change in the target.